# Android Developer Tools(ADT) installation gives GTK errors when not run as sudo

Tags: linux, installation, eclipse

I installed the Android Developer Tools (ADT) bundle, which includes the Eclipse platform, on Ubuntu 12.10, using the [official instructions](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/bundle.html). When I run the program from the command line I see this message 8 times:

> LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed

When I exit I get:

> (ADT:5170): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion  `GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed
>
> (ADT:5170): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed
>
> (ADT:5170): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed
>
> (ADT:5170): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed
>
> (ADT:5170): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed
>
> (ADT:5170): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.
>
> (ADT:5170): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed
>
> (ADT:5170): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed

What is going wrong? 
and
Should I expect ADT to work normally, or with some errors, or with reduced functionality?

**UPDATE**

When running as `sudo`:

> sudo adt-bundle-linux-x86_64/eclipse/eclipse

there are no GTK errors. How can I run ADT/Eclipse without `sudo` and without running into the GTK errors.

Comment: running as `sudo` gives me no GTK errors. Now I'm wondering how to run this without sudo and without those errors.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, just run it and see if it behaves normally. No need to rely on expectations :)

The errors you are getting are GTK error messages. These are seldom, if ever, important and have nothing to do with the core functionality of the program throwing them. They usually mean that there are some outdated elements in the program's GUI. I would not worry about them too much.

As as I said earlier though, just try and see.

Comment: The problem is I am inexperienced with Eclipse/ADT. If the GTK error messages are in reference to the GUI I would be worried about such things as missing menu items.

As far as I can tell with my limited experience, it appears to be working OK.

Comment: They are usually problems with the GTK theme engine, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @chobok If eunning as root does not give the errors, you can safely ignore them. They will depend on personal settings you have (probably in ~/.config) and should not affect the function of the program in any way.

Answer (score 0):

I too face this problem. The fix to this as mentioned above is to run eclipse with sudo but this creates problems in the future. If you are using build tools like maven or gradle you will face permission related issues as the tools cannot write to the target folder.

Before this the 64bit architecture machines must have needed the below.

sudo apt-get install ia32-libs

as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250168/android-developer-tools-adt-installation-gives-gtk-errors-when-not-run-as-sudo). The sudo to install the ia32-libs is the root cause of the problem. After installing the ia32-libs when you try to launch eclipse, the access to these libs is restricted and you are forced to use sudo to successfully launch eclipse. Need some Linux gurus to help with the permissions while installing the ia32-libs, if this can be done, without the sudo, it will make life much easier. Below are the errors I get when installing the ia32-libs without sudo.

E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

Answer (score 0):

You can try set environment variable UBUNTU_MENUPROXY to 0. This solved my problem.